# Comparing chars with spanish characters

Tags: c++, char, compare, character

I have a input with any character and i need to have a array that separates the words in the input. The array needs to have just the letters (is in spanish, so it includes accented letters). My code does it, it just fails to recognize the special spanish characters as "¡", "¿", etc.

how can i manage to correct this?... here is my code.

```
string x[100];
int n = 0;
while (entrada){
    entrada>>x[n];
    n++;
}
n--;
for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
    cout<<x[j]<<"/";
}
string y[100];
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<x[i].length();j++){
        if(!ispunct(x[i][j]))
            y[i]+=x[i][j];
    }
```

with this code I got this input and output:

```
input
=======
Hola,
Cómo estás?
Espero que muy bien. ¡!!!
El otro día que fui al cine me acordé de la
película que vimos el año pasado.

output
========
Hola/Cómo/estás/Espero/que/muy/bien/¡/El/otro/día/que/fui/al/cine/me/acordé/de/la/película/que/vimos/el/año/pasado/
```

the output is just the array printed separated by a "/"

Comment: Intenta crear un arreglo de caracteres con los signos válidos, incluidas letras acentuadas, minúsculas y mayúsculas, así haces un ciclo doble, el cual compares que exista el caracter en el arreglo, de no ser así, puedes validar que no es correcto.

Comment: Try to create an array of valid chars, with a double for, you can compare each element to the valid array, and validate if its correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the locale, something like this:

```
  #include <clocale>
  ...
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
```

It should make `ispunct()` recognize Spanish punctuators.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.. got exactly the same result

Comment: Did it return `NULL`? And how exactly did you encode your Spanish text? UTF-8? 8859-something? Something else? What are your compiler and OS?

Comment: i just added your code, so i have:

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <clocale>
#include "AD.h"
using namespace std;
    int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
    ifstream entrada;

    entrada.open("entrada.txt");
    string x[100];
    int n = 0;
    while (entrada){
        entrada>>x[n];
        n++;
    }
    n--;
    
    string y[100];
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<x[i].length();j++){
            if(!ispunct(x[i][j]))
                y[i]+=tolower(x[i][j]);
        }
    for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
        cout<<y[j]<<"/";
    }
}